# Emacs doesn't search inside elpa directory while loading

Tags: init-file, package-repositories, load-path

OS: Windows XP, Emacs: 24.5.1.

I installed bookmark+ package using Melpa. It was put into directory:

```
~/.emacs.d/elpa/bookmark+-20151107.847
```

When I put `(require 'bookmark+)` to the end of ~/.emacs, I get an error:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `.emacs':

File error: Cannot open load file, no such file or directory, bookmark+
```

But after Emacs is fully loaded, if I evaluate form `(require 'bookmark+)` --- it loads the appropriate module.

So, it seems, that it doesn't search for the library in `~/.emacs.d/elpa/bookmark+-20151107.847` directory while `.emacs` is being loaded.

How to fix?

Comment: This is a duplicate of StackOverflow question [Emacs 24 Package System Initialization Problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127109/emacs-24-package-system-initialization-problems).

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line to your `init.el` file before you require the package `(require 'bookmark+)`.

```
(package-initialize)
```

Comment: This is *not* the way to deal with ELPA packages.

Comment: Sorry for not reading the question so carefully. So `package-initialize`will be needed.

Comment: Adding manually to `load-path` was indeed not right, but calling `package-initialize` is the right solution.  Emacs-25 will even automatically add that call to your `~/.emacs` (in some cases) if you haven't done so yet.

Comment: @YoungFrog: the autoloads will be setup by `package-initialize`, so calling `package-initialize` is the right thing to do regardless of whether you want to `require` the package or not.

Comment: @Stefan I meant that since the autoloads exist, `require` is not needed. And if `require` is not used, then the problem disappears (because `package-initialize` is called by emacs). [But my comment was badly written (it took me a few seconds to understand it), so I've just deleted it.]